# Why was the statement of Ben Hei Hei added at the end of Pirkei Avos 5?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof

The Alter Rebbe of Lubavitch [writes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25076&st=&pgnum=460&hilite=):

> ואף גם זאת דבן ה' למקרא היא
>   ברייתא שלא הובאה בגמרא, ואינה משנה לגירסת הרמב"ם בפירוש המשניות עיין שם במדרש
>   שמואל

That the statement of Ben Hei Hei commonly printed at the end of chapter 5 is not part of the Mishna of Pirkei Avos according to the Rambam and the Medrash Shmuel, rather it is a Braisa that is not brought in the Gemara (and thus could arguably not be relevant to psak halacha).

In addition, Double AA [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/what-are-the-mishnah-and-gemara-referenced-in-pirkei-avot-5#comment85378_33524) that [older manuscripts](http://kaufmann.mtak.hu/en/ms50/ms50-173v.htm) of the Mishna don't include it.

I have heard of editions of Pirkei Avos that puts the statement *before* the end, perhaps to avoid finishing with something negative.

So given all of that, why was it added at all?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep

Comment: What does this have to do with Ben Hei Hei? Isn't it a statement of יהודה בן תימא about what ages are appropriate for what kinds of learning?

Comment: @paquda, depends on your Girsa who the statement is attributed to.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know. I see now that that was discussed in the linked question.

Comment: you may be interested in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61227