# Is Ever Min HaHai a Nevelah?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Does Ever Min HaHai have a Din of Nevelah? Does it render food cooked with it Nevelah? If it's meat from a Behemah Tehorah would it be Asur to cook with milk?

Comment: See tosfot shevuot 24a dh HaOchel

Comment: Also, unless you produce a reasonable nafka minah, I think this should be tagged [tag:lomdus] not [tag:halacha].

Comment: What do you mean? I gave two [Nafkei Minah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18483/5).

Comment: "Does it render food cooked with it Nevelah?": it would render it either Nevelah or EM"H, but what's the difference? They're both issurei lav. I don't see how that's a Nafka Minah. Whatever the status of the issur is, that is the status it will impart to food it is cooked with.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a נבילה.* (Nafka Mina if one gave warning to someone who was about to eat an אבר מן החי that he would be חייב because of לא תאכלו כל נבילה, he would be פטור.) Food cooked with it would have the law of אבר מן החי, not נבילה. They are two separate דינים.

### *This is what seems to be from ’שולחן ערוך יו''ד סי’ סב סע’ ב, as it says that אמ''ה is a טריפה, not a נבילה.

In terms of there being a problem of בשר בחלב between an אבר מן החי and milk, this would be a question of איסור חל על איסור. Being that the אמ''ה is previously אסור because of אמ''ה, it cannot further receive the איסור of בשר חלב (or any other איסור, for that matter). Furthermore, even נבילה itself if cooked with milk will not be בשר בחלב, as is explained by the רמב''ם in the third chapter of מסכת כריתות, fourth Mishna. His point applies to אמ''ה also; no איסור can be חל on any other איסור unless it adds on more people or things in the איסור (i.e. מוסיף וכולל), and being that בשר בחלב is in essence a prohibition from eating (even though it is also אסור בהנאה) it cannot be חל on another איסור אכילה like אבר מן החי or נבילה.

- ויש בדברינו אלה נקודה נפלאה נעיר עליה, לפי שהיא מפתח לענינים אחרים נוסף למה שיש בה מדייוק העיון, והיא, מן הידוע שבשר בחלב אסור בהנאה, והחלב דרך משל מותר בהנאה, ואם בשל החלב בחלב מה טעם לא יחול אסור בשר בחלב על אסור חלב, והוא הדין בנבלה, בהיותו אסור מוסיף כמו שאמרנו כאן בחלב הקדשים וחייבנו על אכילתו מעילה מחמת שנוסף בו אסור הנאה, ו**התשובה לכך שבשר בחלב לא נאסר בהנאה אלא מחמת שאסר הכתוב אכילתו לפי הכלל שבארנו שכל שנאסר באכילה נאסר ליהנות בו עד שיפרוט לך הכתוב**, ואין בו פסוק האוסר אכילתו ופסוק האוסר ליהנות בו, אלא שני הדברים יחד הם אסור בשר בחלב, וכיון שאמרנו אין אסור חל על אסור ולפיכך לא יחול אסור בשר בחלב על אסור נבלה הרי לא יהא אסור בהנאה אלא יהא מותר בהנאה והאוכלו לוקה משום נבלה, וירד אסור בשר בחלב לגמרי לפי שלא חל

Comment: +1 for the second half; but any source for your first sentence? Also, why isn't the _isur basar b'chalav_ adding in that it applies to the milk?

Comment: @msh210: it is not the milk itself that is assur, but the mixture. However, that is not the point. The point is that because בב''ח is basically a high level איסור אכילה it would not be "adding" a new איסור but just making the previous איסור more אסור. That is why I quoted the רמב''ם. source for the first statement is pending.

Comment: i just italicized the part of the רמב''ם that i was talking about

Comment: for a good definition of איסורי כולל ומוסיף, see כריתות דף יד. רש''י ד''ה מיגו.

Comment: But most rishonim do not accept that Rambam.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch does not say it is a tereifah. It learns it from a pasuk that uses the word tereifah; those are different things. Moreover if you follow the drasha back to the gemara that pasuk is only used to learn basar min hachai not ever min hachai.

Comment: @DoubleAA which rishonim?

Comment: moses, I wasn't saying it's more of an _isur_ because of the _hanaa_. I was proposing it's an _isur_ on more things because of the milk. Isn't "_isur_ on more things" another way of beating "_en isur chal al isur_"?