# Why are "Chiddushei" seforim rarely cited in the Nosi Keilim?

Tags: history, jewish-books, halacha-theory

I noticed that when quoting Rishonim, Beis Yosef/Nosei Keilim tend to focus on Poskim (Rif (and main commentary)/Rosh/Rambam, Mordechai, Teruma, Rabbeinu Yerucham, etc.) and responsa.

Very rarely do you find "Chiddushim" seforim (like Chiddushei Rashba, Ritva, Ramban, Peirush Hamishnayos of the Rambam  [except in Mikvaos], the Rash [ditto]).

Why is that? Tosfos are still fairly commonly quoted but no "Gemara peirush" since then. I would assume that the Rashba's explanations of the Gemara could bring [Nafka Minas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/plural-of-nafka-minah) to the table. If it's because it wasn't written as a "psak", well, neither was Tosfos.

Comment: `Very rarely do you find "Chiddushim" seforim.` I wouldn't go that far at all. The *Beit Yosef*, for one example, cites them with some regularity - most especially the *Chiddushei HaRashba*.

Comment: @Fred although in some areas he cites the Toras HaBayis pretty much exclusively, and sometimes interprets it in ways contrary to the implications of the Chiddushim.  I think much of it wasn't available to him.

Comment: @YeZ and Toras HaBais is a "Psak" sefer

Comment: My assumption was that these rishonim simply weren't available to him, but it's possible that there were ideological reasons as well. I'll have to run a computer test though to see if you're right about chidushei rashba; I feel like he quotes it as often as rabbeinu yerucham or Sefer heterumah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin that was my point, yes.

Comment: I assume שיטת רש״י is frequently quoted

Comment: I think a lot of these weren't printed