# What is special about Tzfat?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, cities

The city of Tzefat seems to be a magnet for torah scholars and kabbalists for many hundreds of years. Why is that?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9403/759

Comment: also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12911

Answer (score 1):

It was the home of one of the greatest, some would say the greatest, kabbalists of all time, [Yitzack Luria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Luria), commonly known as the Ari. It was also one of [four holy cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Holy_Cities) in Eretz Yisrael where jews lived before the beginning of the modern Aliyahs

Comment: The Ari only lived in Tzfas for 3 years. Before he came, the [Rama"k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Jacob_Cordovero) was already living and teaching in Tzfas.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12911/759

Comment: If the four cities only holy because that's where people lived, then you're logic is circular: Why did they live there? Because it was holy. Why was it holy? Because they live there.

Comment: It's one of the four holy cities "where" jews lived not because.

Comment: of all time? wasn't Rabbi Shimon far greater